# Textbox does not linebreak within expander control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an ItemsControl with many Expander with inside a TextBox.

The TextBox has long Text but its text does not line wrap instead I see a horizontal Scrollbar on the ItemsControl which I do not want. I want the horizontal Scrollbar on the Textbox. Event that I do not want instead the text in the Textobx should always wrap and wrap and have a Vertical Scrollbar.

How can I do that?

```
<Window x:Class="ExpanderTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalTemplate">
            <Expander Margin="0" Header="{Binding FileName}" Background="Green">
                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"  IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Content}"  Margin="0"/>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ErrorLogs}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource NormalTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>


public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            GetErrorLogs();
        }

        private void GetErrorLogs()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                string content = new string('0', 500 * i + 1);
                var e = new ErrorLogViewModel { Content = content, FileName = "ErrorLog " + i };
                ErrorLogs.Add(e);
            }

        }

        private ObservableCollection<ErrorLogViewModel> _errorLogs = new ObservableCollection<ErrorLogViewModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<ErrorLogViewModel> ErrorLogs
        {
            get { return _errorLogs; }
            set
            {
                _errorLogs = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ErrorLogs");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default template for a `ListBox` contains a `ScrollViewer` control to present your items. This ScrollViewer shows the scroll bars.

In order to disable the horizontal scroll bar, set the following property on the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...
```